# Pointer-to-Pointer-to-Const Conversion

Tags: c++, constants, pointer-conversion

I'm reading a book called [C++ Gotchas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125185) which explains the conversions between const pointers and I'm having some trouble understanding the following rules:

> Two pointer types T1 and T2 are similar if there exists a type T and
>   integer n > 0 such that:
>
> T1 is *cv* 1 , 0 pointer to *cv* 1,1 pointer to . . . *cv* 1,n−1
>   pointer to *cv* 1,n T
>
> and,
>
> T2 is *cv* 2,0 pointer to *cv* 2,1 pointer to . . . *cv* 2,n−1
>   pointer to *cv* 2,n T
>
> where each cvi,j is const, volatile, const volatile, or nothing.

Can someone point me to right direction where I can get an explanation or is anyone familiar with what ***cv* 1,0** and ***cv* 1,1** means in each of above sequence ? The book isn't helping me enough to understand it. But I'm sure this has got something to do with C++ language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cv i,j` represents a collection of 2*(n+1) placeholders:

For every combination of `i` with `1 <= i <= 2` and `j` with `0 <= j <= n` the placeholder `cv i,j` stands for one of the three specifiers `const,volatile, const volatlie` or nothing.

The book excerpt in other words means, that if these placeholders and a type `T` can be found such that the two statements ("T1 is ..") are satisfied, then `T1` and `T2` are called "similar".

For example `T1 = const int*` and `T2 = int*` are similar, because they fullfill the two statements from the excerpt, if one chooses:

- `T = int`,`n = 1`
- `cv1,0= {nothing}` and `cv1,1 = const`
- `cv2,0={nothing}` and `cv2,1 = {nothing}`

To see this, just insert the placeholders:

`const int*` is pointer to `const int`

`int*` is pointer to `int`